# Understanding these SNP annotations

Tags: gene-annotation, snp

I am looking at the [PharmaPGKB](http://www.pharmgkb.org/index.jsp) database for SNPs and trying to understand what the following [annotation](http://www.pharmgkb.org/rsid/rs1801131) means:

```
rs1801131 at 1:11854475 in CLCN6, MTHFR (VIP)
```

Ok, the SNP identified by `rs1801131` occurs in the first chromosome, at position `11854475`.

Then, the two genes' identifiers come. The position `11854475` is inside the gene `MTHFR`. Why do they also annotate the SNP to the gene `CLCN6` (which is a "neighbour" of `MTHFR`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the two genes overlap:

[image]

CLCN6 is on the plus strand and MTHFR is on the minus strand. The SNP is annotated to both because it falls in a region of the genome claimed by both genes.